# Converting varbinary data to varchar in SQL (Just like converting bytearray to string using ASCII.Default.GetString in c#)

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I need to fix some data conversion issue in SQL Server 2008. I got some requirement change on storing the data. Without much care I converted existing `varbinary` data to `varchar` in SQL Server 2008 using

```
CONVERT(NVARCHAR(max), @bytearraydata, 1)
```

The same conversion in C# is done using `ASCII.Default.GetString` and `ASCII.Default.GetBytes` api's. `ASCII.Default.GetBytes(string)` gets back the byte array as it was earlier. But when I try to get back the byte array of string which I converted using `CONVERT()` method of SQL Server 2008 I get a wrong result.

I have to do the byte array to string conversion for existing data via DB scripts only.

Answer (score 0):

From the MSDN reference it shows conversion from Varbinary to VarChar supports implicit conversion, that means you do not really need to use CONVERT function. Just assign the value, SQL will take care of the rest, have you tried that ?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx